# Call IntersectionObserver callback again after it has observed an element?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I am observing messages and keep track of these observations using message timestamps. There's an important condition for these observations: the tracking timestamp shouldn't update if there's no client activity on the page (cursor not moving, or he's not typing anything). Quite often client gets a new message, but has no activity. That means that Observer is skipping that element once it's fully observed. But when user actually provides some activity this element is not re-observed, that means that observer callback is never called again unless the ratio changes. How do I tell IS to recalculate all the observations to trigger my callback?

The problem with manually 're-observing' elements is that the callback is never called if the element is already within intersection bounds.

Some pseudo-code for example:

```
IS.callback = function(entries, observer){
    for (var entry in entries)
    {
        if (activity && entries.hasOwnProperty(entry))
        {
            if (lastTimestamp < entries[entry].data.timestamp)
                lastTimestamp = entries[entry].data.timestamp;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple: remove any observers and observe elements once again. Then call `startObserve();` on any activity change. Using jQuery here for simplicity.

```
function startObserve()
{
    IS.targets =
        $('#messages .message')
        .each(function(index, target){
            IS.observer.unobserve(target);
            IS.observer.observe(target);
        });
}
```